# Quickest and best way to determine Angular/AngularJS version a site is using?

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular, asp.net-mvc

At work, I've inherited over 30 web sites/applications built using C#, ASP.NET, MVC and AngularJS/Angular. The sites were built and updated between 2010 and 2018. Some have been built and updated more recently than others. What is the quickest and best way to determine decisively what version of AngularJS or Angular each site is using?

For the record, I don't have any Angular experience yet, other than a few modifications to some of these sites. My background is in C#, ASP.NET, MVC, React, JS, PHP, VB6 etc. The technologies and design decisions used for these sites were an interesting choice, which wasn't mine to make, so please don't get too excited about them. What I find will determine which version of Angular I will focus on learning initially.

Comment: `package.json` look at the version of `angular/core`

Comment: Keep in mind that web pages can also be a hybrid because the two frameworks were designed to run side-by-side to allow incremental migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question basically is how to determine `AngularJS` vs `Angular`. The Angular version from 2 to 8 does not really matter.

For AngularJS, the quickest way is to spot `$scope` in the JS file, which means it is built in AngularJS.

Comment: Just look at the actual version in `package.json` no need to infer it

Comment: I believe the a single project has a mix of `AngularJS` and `Angular` files. If not `package.json` will help.

Comment: Based on what do you believe that? OP didn't say that

Comment: @DetectivePikachu "AngularJS/Angular" and "determine decisively what version of AngularJS or Angular"

Comment: @AFriend Nothing about that implies that it is all mixed into a single project. It only implies that OP doesn't know if the projects he has are aJS or a2+